# Object destructuring in an arrow function doesn't need to refer to the object itself?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I'm currently practicing destructuring on freecodecamp and came across this case

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};
```

CASE : Use destructuring assignment within the argument to the function **half** to send only **max** and **min** inside the function.

```
// Only change code below this line
const half = (stats) => (stats.max + stats.min) / 2.0; 
// Only change code above this line
```

I'm supposed to use destructuring method on the arrow function and the solution was to remove the word **stats**, which is the name of the object. This is supposed to be the answer:

```
const half = ({max,min}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

What i want to know is why don't i need to refer max & min inside the parameter bracket to the **stats** object? how does the code knows which max & min is the function referring to?

Answer (score 1):

"The Modern Javascript Tutorial" [writes](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring):

> The destructuring assignment also works with objects.
>
> The basic syntax is:
>
> ```
> let {var1, var2} = {var1:…, var2:…}
> ```
>
> We should have an existing object on the right side, that we want to split into variables. The left side contains an object-like “pattern” for corresponding properties. In the simplest case, that’s a list of variable names in {...}.

Notice how the same names occur on both sides.

> For instance:
>
> ```
> let options = {
>   title: "Menu",
>   width: 100,
>   height: 200
> };
>
> let {title, width, height} = options;
>
> alert(title);  // Menu
> alert(width);  // 100
> alert(height); // 200
> ```
>
> Properties `options.title`, `options.width` and `options.height` are assigned to the corresponding variables.
>
> The order does not matter. This works too:
>
> ```
> // changed the order in let {...}
> let {height, width, title} = { title: "Menu", height: 200, width: 100 }
> ```
>
> The pattern on the left side may be more complex and specify the mapping between properties and variables.
>
> If we want to assign a property to a variable with another name, for instance, make options.width go into the variable named w, then we can set the variable name using a colon:
>
> ```
> let options = {
>   title: "Menu",
>   width: 100,
>   height: 200
> };
>
> // { sourceProperty: targetVariable }
> let {width: w, height: h, title} = options;
>
> // width -> w
> // height -> h
> // title -> title
> alert(title);  // Menu
> alert(w);      // 100
> alert(h);      // 200
> ```

And it works exactly the same way in a function call. After all, a function call is executed by assigning the argument to the parameter, so if you write

```
const calculateAvg = ({min,max}) => (min + max) / 2.0;
const avg = calculateAvg(obj);
```

It's executed as if you had written

```
const {min, max} = obj; // assign argument to parameter
const returnValue = (min + max) / 2.0; // execute the function
const avg = returnValue; // assign the return value
```

So when you write:

```
({max,min}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

it defines a local variable `max` that receives the `max` property of the object passed, and a local variable `min` that receives the `min` property of the object passed.

Comment: please bear with me, i'm a beginner here. i understand your examples. however, the examples you've shown use `= options` at the end of the destructuring. That part i see as the part where we refer the object we want to destructure. but in my case, the solution didn't use that referring. that's what i'm having problem understanding

Answer (score 0):

Because it is the first argument.

For comparison, consider this:

```js
const regular = (first, second) => console.log(`regular: ${first.foo} and ${second.bar}`);

const destructured = ({foo}, {bar}) => console.log(`destructured: ${foo} and ${bar}`);


const x = { foo: 1 };
const y = { bar: 2 };

regular(x, y);
destructured(x, y);
```

Comment: so does this mean that any first argument i made after an object, it will always refer to that object? what if i have a nested object?

Comment: "so does this mean that any first argument i made after an object" — No. It means that the first value you pass to a function is assigned to the first position in the argument list. If that position has a variable name it is assigned to that variable. If that position has destructuring syntax, then it is destructured.

Comment: "what if i have a nested object?" — I'm sure the MDN documentation covers the syntax for using destructuring with nested objects.